# Cannot connect iOS using AFNetworking to asp.net webservices

Tags: asp.net, ios, objective-c, web-services, afnetworking

I am trying to connect from iOS to asp.net webservices and i am getting error 500.  The webservices are working if connected from the web using jQuery.ajax but not from iOS.  Are there any settings that have to be set on the server side to allow the connection?  Possibly some security settings that are not allowing outside connections?  How do i make sure that the webserice is returning json.  When i try to enter the url directly into the browser i get the webservices directory and i can invoke the webservice but i get an error.  Everything is working perfectly from the website though.  Here is the code that i am using from the iOS side

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"user", @"userName",@"test", @"password",nil],@"request",nil];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.server.com"]];
    //[client setDefaultHeader:@"contentType" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"];
    client.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =
    [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/mobile/user.asmx/login" parameters:params];
    NSLog(@"request %@",request);
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                            success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
    {
          NSLog(@"response %@",response);
          NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"LoginResult"]);
          NSLog(@"Code: %@", [[[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"LoginResult"] valueForKeyPath:@"Code"] stringValue]);
          NSLog(@"FaultString: %@", [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"LoginResult"] valueForKeyPath:@"FaultString"]);
             }
             failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
             {
                 NSLog(@"error opening connection %d %@",response.statusCode, error);
                 NSLog(@"request %@",request);
             }];
[operation start];
}
```

and this is the code that works on the website

```
$('#signin').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var user = $('#user').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            var holdval = "<ul>";
            if (user == null || user == "")
                holdval += "<li>Provide user name</li>";

            if (password == null || password == "")
                holdval += "<li>Provide password</li>";

            holdval += "</ul>";
            if (holdval != "<ul></ul>") {
                $('#msg').show();
                $('#msg').html(holdval);
                return;
            }

            var temp = new User(user, password);
            $("#loader").show();
            var jsontxt = JSON.stringify({ user: temp });
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/mobile/user.asmx/login", //http://www.server.com

                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                data: jsontxt,
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnError
            });
        });
```

UPDATE

As Cory suggested i used wireshark and check out the http traffic.  Turned out the request is a GET request but i am still not able to get this working.  The issues is the website request passes json data with username and afnetworking passes just username and password

This is from the website
http://www.server.com/user.asmx/loginuser{%22user%22:%22username%22,%22password%22:%22pass%22}

This is from iOS
http://www.server.com/user.asmx/loginuser?password=pass&user=username

It seems to me that the parameters are not becoming json

Here is the updated code that i am using on iOS

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.server.com/user.asmx/"]];
    [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"contentType" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"];
[httpClient getPath:@"loginuser" parameters:@{@"user":@"username",@"password":@"pass"} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE 2
After adding this in the first code above with afsjonrequestoperation

```
[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:USERNAME password:USER_PASSWORD]; //setting authorization header
[client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"login/" parameters:nil]; //parameter nil
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

I am not getting any errors or responses after i start the operation but if i check wireshark i am getting 401 Unauthorized and and html saying that credentials are invalid. I am sure that username and password are correct.  I am not sure if this is step further then i was before.  Please let me know what you think.  Thanks again!

Comment: You could use a proxy like [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to inspect the raw HTTP requests from the ajax and iOS requests to figure out the differences.

Comment: You need to put the json encoded parameters in the request body.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to do that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`GET` requests will serialize parameters in the query string, because according to [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), `GET` requests shouldn't include an entity body.

For your particular case, you can get this to work by using the code above (creating the `POST` request as before), but adding the following line immediately after:

`[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You are talking about the first code sample?  I added the line you suggested right before [operation start] is that right?  I am still getting the same error error opening connection 500 Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 500" UserInfo=0x8cab0a0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""},  I am thinking that there still something wrong with the request.

Comment: I misspoke. That should have been GET. A 500 error means that the problem is on the server.

Comment: After making the changes you suggested i am getting error opening connection 0 Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)"  I am sure there is no problem with the connection.  Can you see what else can it be.  Is there way to check what actually is being send to the server.  I am using wireshark but i can only see the link with out the username and password parameters  Do you think it could be some settings on the server? The website is working with out a problem.  Thanks a million!

Comment: At this point, it's up to you to debug your server, as that seems to be the problem. [AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger) should help with that.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I am going to work with the person who built the webservices to see if we can pinpoint the issue on the server side.